# Diskstation (Networkshare) - Deleted File but Space still in Use

Tags: linux, unix, filesystems, nas, synology

So I've been trying to clear up some space on my backup drive.

The Volume is 17TB in Size but it's in use by 96%. Now, I deleted a 2.5TB File but the usage isn't going down. I've went ahead and looked at my drive.

```
du -sh
```

Lists all files that are there. The file is not listed.

```
df -h
```

Tells me that it's not just a synology GUI glitch (96% in use)

I've tried restarting since, it didn't change anything so the file wasn't in use (though I double checked and made sure it wasn't anyway)

Any ideas?

Edit:
Synology seems to employ some sort of UNIX or Linux. There is no .Trash directory.

Answer (score 2):

Your shared folder may have Recycle Bin enabled. The directory is called `#recycle` (not `.Trash`).

Go to Control Panel, Shared Folders, select your shared folder and click Edit. If the `Enable Recycle Bin` checkbox is active you can try to empty the recycle bin from there and see if you get more storage. It may take a while to see the change.

Comment: The recycle bin is not enabled. It would seem that the files are matching up with the space used as well, for some reason my volume is no longer 16TB but around 14-ish now.